# Qt: Include .pri to use library - incorrect includes

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qmake, qtserialport

I'm trying to use QtSerialPort (http://qt-project.org/wiki/QtSerialPort) with Qt 4.8. It's not part of that version, so I have to install it manually.
To avoid to manually install it, I just wanted to include the .pri file that is shipped with QtSerialPort.
I got my copy by doing "git clone https://git.gitorious.org/qt/qtserialport.git".
Using it in my *.pro file with:

```
include(qtserialport/src/serialport/serialport-lib.pri)
```

But compiling fails bc. of includes like:

```
#include <QtSerialPort/qserialportglobal.h>
```

So I guess these includes resolve to something like /usr/include etc. Is there any way to fix this without changing all the includes from  to "foo.h" manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I guess these includes resolve to something like /usr/include etc. Is there any way to fix this without changing all the includes from to "foo.h" manually?

Yes, sure.

First, you would need to write `CONFIG += serialport` as per documentation.

You could also specify the includepath to the qtserialport clone on your system.

You would still need to get the library built, but I assume that you are aware of it.

Comment: Mh you make it sound like I still need to "make install" QtSerialPort. I used QExtSerialPort before and I just needed to include the .pri file and the includes were in my path. What breaks the same scheme with QtSerialPort is, that internally it includes its own files with <QSerialPort>, unlike QExtSerialPort, which used include "qextserailport.h"

Comment: Building and installing are different stages. I intentionally wrote building, and not installing. As for QextSerialPort, I would assume it is a bug since if you move the public header to a different location, the relativity would break, and that is not good for public headers. As far as I know, this is a generic style in Qt. See for instance QtLocation or QtSensors for examples.

Comment: OK, I see. But Including the .pri in my .pro should take care of building (it did with QExtSerialPort). Building leaves me with the .so and a .prl. But I'd prefer to have my project build completely for every platform and not build the library extra.
qserialport.h does have "#include <QtSerialPort/qserialportglobal.h>" in it. Compiler complained about not finding QtSerialPort

Comment: You will get an include/QtSerialPort folder generated in the qtserialport project root, so you will be able to add that include path to your includepath.

Comment: @BenjaminMaurer: If you include the .prf file rather than the .pri, it will work fine just like with the examples since the include path will be added automatically. See this: `$projectroot/src/serialport/qt4support/serialport.prf`.

Comment: Thank you for your help Laslo. I'm only working part time, so I'll have to wait until Monday to try it :) I'll let you know how it turned out.

Comment: OK, so I have built the library, opened my .pro file, right click -> add library and selected the Shared Library. I have to add include paths for both bin/include and bin/include/QtSerialPort, or else I still get error messages. But it works. Thank you very much!